# JQuery Attr visible not working with IE7 or below

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a page in which I enable, and make the button visible using JQuery. This is what I am using:

```
//disable save until validated
$("#btnSave").attr("disabled", true);
```

Once the validation of a component is completed, I enable the save button:

```
$("#btnSave").attr("disabled", false);
```

**Problem:** It works find with Chrome, FF, IE8+, but does not work with IE7 and below (surprised :O ). Is there any hack for this or a workaround this issue.

Comment: try `$("#btnSave").prop("disabled", false);`

Comment: I have tried this, but the button remains hidden.

Comment: @faizanjehangir - you're just enable/disabling a button, are you handling hide & show as well? if yes.. then use .show() & .hide()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `prop` instead of `attr`

```
$("#btnSave").prop("disabled", false);
```

If you want to use `attr` (although I'd prefer not to but for the sake of completion)

```
$('#btnSave').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
```

Answer (score 3):

Directly taken from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> "To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method."

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has stated, you need to use `$("#btnSave").prop("disabled", false);`

**But why?** Because IE8 only accepts the disabled property as:

```
<button disabled="disabled">
```

You instructed jQuery to set the literal value of the attribute to "true", resulting in:

```
<button disabled="true">
```

However, using `.prop`, jQuery will automagically set the correct value for that attribute, whether it be checked/selected/disabled, or just a literal attribute value.

Comment: Acually, `.prop()` will not touch the attribute at all but set the `.disabled` property of the DOM Element instead

Comment: @ThiefMaster Good clarification, that's what I was getting at with the last sentence, but you put it better so I'll just +1 your comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

**EXAMPLE**

```
  $(function(){
    $('#button1').prop('disabled', true);
       // $('#button1').prop('disabled', null);//if you want to enable it
    });
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CKgf6/9/).